# Redundant template instantiations left over by MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I was experimenting with some template programming on the compiler explorer when I noticed that MSVC left a lot of templated function definitions in the assembly output even though they were optimized out of the main function and not called at any point; this is in contrast to GCC which does not include them. I checked using my installation of Visual Studio 2019 (16.1.3) and the output is the same as the compiler explorer's.

Are there any combinations of [compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=vs-2019) and [linker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options?view=vs-2019) flags, or directives I can give in the source, which will remove these from the binary? I have tried combinations involving /O1 but to no avail.

The [code I used is](https://godbolt.org/z/-cwdkO)

```
template <unsigned int N>
constexpr unsigned int fact()
{
    return N * fact<N-1>();
}

template <>
constexpr unsigned int fact<0>()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    return fact<4>();
}
```

The GCC output is

```
main:
        mov     eax, 24
        ret
```

and from MSVC

```
unsigned int fact<1>(void) PROC                       ; fact<1>, COMDAT
        mov     eax, 1
        ret     0
unsigned int fact<1>(void) ENDP                       ; fact<1>

etc...

unsigned int fact<4>(void) PROC                       ; fact<4>, COMDAT
        mov     eax, 24
        ret     0
unsigned int fact<4>(void) ENDP                       ; fact<4>

unsigned int fact<0>(void) PROC                                ; fact<0>, COMDAT
        mov     eax, 1
        ret     0
unsigned int fact<0>(void) ENDP                                ; fact<0>

main    PROC                                            ; COMDAT
        mov     eax, 24
        ret     0
main    ENDP
```

whereas I am hoping to find a way for it to simply emit

```
main    PROC                                            ; COMDAT
        mov     eax, 24
        ret     0
main    ENDP
```

Comment: Did you try compiler:`/GL` and linker:`/LTCG`?

Comment: I’ve just tried /GL but isn’t recognised, I have used /LTCG

Comment: Godbolt output shows translation unit content, those unused functions won't be included into final executable. Linking is not performed at all.

Comment: @VTT that should be the answer, not a comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554894/relation-between-msvc-compiler-linker-option-for-comdat-folding

Comment: @darune This question is about MSVC not about how godbolt.org works and displays the result.

Comment: I thought it might be godbolt missing a step, as I know it doesn't produce executable code (at least for MSVC) which is why I looked at the disassembly when I compiled the same code on my computer. I'm guessing the disassembly is thus free to include extra code from pdb/source files not present in the final binary?

Comment: [dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=vs-2019) can be used to inspect content of executable