# Why does MSVC compiler put template instantiation binaries in assembly?

Tags: c++, templates

I encountered something weird in the MSVC compiler.

it puts function template definition in assembly while optimization eliminates the need for them.
It seems that Clang and GCC successfully remove function definition at all but MSVC does not.

Can it be fixed?

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int n> int value() noexcept
{
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    return value<5>() + value<10>();
}
```

assembly:

```
int value<5>(void) PROC                                ; value<5>, COMDAT
        mov     eax, 5
        ret     0
int value<5>(void) ENDP                                ; value<5>

int value<10>(void) PROC                                ; value<10>, COMDAT
        mov     eax, 10
        ret     0
int value<10>(void) ENDP                                ; value<10>

main    PROC                                            ; COMDAT
        mov     eax, 15
        ret     0
main    ENDP
```

[Sample code on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sbx6G4v3q)

Comment: This is just because of how godbolt compiles the code (basically it doesn't fully compile for MSVC, I believe). If you compile using MSVC on your own computer, with "Release" mode, those functions don't exist either.

Comment: with `/GL` switch it compiles to `mov    eax,0xf  ret`

Comment: @ChrisMM I tried on my local machine and the same result happens!

Comment: What settings are you using? The default "Release" mode, in VS 2022, does not have those functions for me....

Comment: @IłyaBursov I tried this too but still, both functions are available in assembly!

Comment: @ChrisMM I compiled the code using VS 2022 with these flags: -arch:AVX -O2 -GR- -FA

Comment: How are you viewing the assembly?

Comment: @ChrisMM by using -FA flag, VS creates main.asm and you can read it.

Comment: That's not the optimized / fully compiled assembly file ...

Comment: @ChrisMM So how do you view the assembly code?

Comment: Duplicate of [Redundant template instantiations left over by MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56699545/redundant-template-instantiations-left-over-by-msvc). (which doesn't have an answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/FA` switch generates the listing file for each translation unit. Since this is *before* the linking stage, MSVC does not determine if those two functions are required anywhere else within the program, and are thus still included in the generated .asm file (Note: this may be for simplicity on MS's part, since it can treat templates the same as regular functions in the generated .obj file, though realistically there's no actual need to store them in the .obj file, as user17732522 points out in the comments).

During linking, MSVC determines that those functions are in fact not actually used / needed anywhere else, and thus can be eliminated (even if they were used elsewhere, since the result can be determined at compile time, they'd still be eliminated) from the compiled executable.

In order to see what's in the final compiled executable, you can view the executable through a disassembler. Example for using MSVC to do this, is put a breakpoint in the main function, run it, then when the breakpoint is hit, right click and "View Disassembly". In this, you will see that the two functions don't exist anymore.

You can also generate the Mapfile using [`/MAP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/map-generate-mapfile?view=msvc-170) option, which also shows it does not exist.

---

**If** I am reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/explicit-instantiation?view=msvc-170) correctly, it seems as those MS chose to include explicit instantiations of templates classes and functions because it "is useful" when creating libraries. Uninstantiated templates are not put into the obj files though.

Comment: Correct. This is done in the linker with the ``/OPT:REF`` switch.

Comment: But implicit template instantiations which aren't used in a object file (because they have been inlined) do not need to be emitted into the object file. They behave like `inline` functions and it is guaranteed that their definitions will be available in each other translation unit requiring it. The compiler could remove them already before the linking phase and thereby reduce time and storage required for the linking procedure. That's how GCC and Clang behave.

Comment: @user17732522, you're right, was thinking normal functions, as opposed to templates with the comment of not being able to remove them before linking. I'll try to rephrase.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `/Zc:inline` to your compile statement and it does the same thing as clang/GCC if you *also* wrap the template in an anonymous namespace to ensure it does not have external visibility.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace
{
    template <int n> int value() noexcept
    {
        return n;
    }
}
```

or if you mark the template function `inline`

```
template <int n> inline int value() noexcept
{
    return n;
}
```

Both result in:

```
main    PROC
        mov     eax, 15
        ret     0
main    ENDP
```

The /Zc:inline *(Remove unreferenced COMDAT)* switch was added in VS 2015 Update 2 as part of the C++11 Standard conformance which allows this optimization.

It is off-by-default in command-line builds. In MSBuild, `<RemoveUnreferencedCodeData>` defaults to true.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/reference/zc-inline-remove-unreferenced-comdat)

**OTHERWISE** It will be cleaned up in the linker phase with `/OPT:REF`.

Comment: I tested -Zc:inline but still definitions exist in main.asm!

Comment: Interesting. The documentation talks only about `inline` functions, but presumably implicit template instantiations are implemented the same way since they effectively follow the same rules as `inline` functions. However as mentioned above this doesn't seem to work, at least on godbolt.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the detail that it must have 'local' scope.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn In your example the template has static linkage. Now there is obviously no reason to emit it since other translation units can't use the template at all. The question is about external linkage templates.

Comment: It works correctly if you make the template `inline`: https://godbolt.org/z/na4dPWWf9 So it really seems they apply this behavior only to inline functions, not implicit template instantiations, which is weird since `inline` has basically no effect on a function template by the standard specification.

Comment: I think the answer to the original question is: "No, it can't be 'fixed' because it's By Design" per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/function-template-instantiation).

Answer (score 1):

I compiled your code as given on my vs2022 in release mode. I get

```
    return value<5>() + value<10>();
00007FF65CD21000  mov         eax,0Fh  
}
00007FF65CD21005  ret
```